# How to find values from one column that occur anywhere in another column of the same table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Okay, let's imagine we have a table (dataframe, tibble) about articles written by authors. Each article has been reviewed by another author, but not all authors are reviewers, e.g.

```
articles <- tibble(author=c("user1", "user2", "user3"), reviewer=c("user2", "user3", "user2"))
> articles
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  author reviewer
  <chr>  <chr>   
1 user1  user2   
2 user2  user3   
3 user3  user2
```

to just look at the columns of interest here. So we can see that `user2` and `user3` have authored articles and are also reviewers. `user1` is not a reviewer. How do we actually return the users who have both authored and reviewed articles? In base R you could do:

```
authors <- unique(articles$author)
reviewers <- unique(articles$reviewer)
> authors[authors %in% reviewers]
[1] "user2" "user3"
```

but how can we do this in the tidyverse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution without joins.

```
articles %>%
  filter(author %in% reviewer) %>%
  select(author) %>%
  distinct()
## A tibble: 2 x 1
#  author
#  <chr> 
#1 user2 
#2 user3
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer! And seems so obvious. It's also clear what you're looking for in what, which so important for reducing that distance from brain to screen!

Answer (score 4):

It feels the answer would likely be in `dplyr`, and I have refined my approach down to:

```
articles %>% 
  semi_join((.), 
    by=c("author"="reviewer")) %>% 
  select(author) %>%
  distinct
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  author
  <chr> 
1 user2 
2 user3
```

This is the correct answer, and I admit I've refined it somewhat even whilst writing this. But has anyone got any alternative takes on the problem? I'm actually quite pleased how it's boiled down, but it took me a little thinking so I'll post it in the hope it helps someone else.

Comment: I think a nice aspect of this solution as well is that it works nicely with a tibble you've created on the fly and it can also work straight away if the two columns are in different tables.

Answer (score 1):

*In `base` we can do:*

```r
unique(articles$author[articles$author %in% articles$reviewer])

 # [1] "user2" "user3"
```